# Creating a login screen using MySQL connector and Python 2.7 Tkinter:

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am having trouble building my program, I need to make a graphical login page for my project and I want to store the data on a MySQL database. I want to build it so that when the user enters their username and password it connects to the correct table in the MySQL database to see if the login details are correct, then their data loads into the program. I thought there might be away of using the user input from python as a query for the database to run. Is there anyway to do this using MySQL and Tkinter, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind these things. 1) Never share the actual username and password outside of the database. 2) Also, hash the password before sharing it outside the Python application. 3) You should try to keep everything encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create your login form as per the tutorial here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh6AdDX7K7U

For the submit button set a command that runs the function which connects to your MySQL server using the values entered in your text boxes and runs the queries.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm